# Better method for acting upon state change in JavaScript classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6, redundancy

I'm trying to move from procedural to object-oriented JavaScript and I'm coming up against an issue I'm sure there's an answer to, but I can't work it out.

Currently, each of my methods checks the state of a property, and then performs an action based on that state. What I'd rather do is update the state and those methods execute as a result of the state change. Is that possible, or am I missing the point?

Here's what I have currently:

```
class ClassExample {
    constructor({state = false} = {}) {
        this.state = state;
        ...
    }

    aMethod() {
        if(this.state) {
            //Do something
            this.state = false;
        } else {
            //Do something else
            this.state = true;
        }
    }

    bMethod() {
        if(this.state) {
            //Do something
            this.state = false;
        } else {
            //Do something else
            this.state = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
const myObject = new ClassExample();
myObject.aMethod();
myObject.bMethod();
```

Given both methods are checking the same property, it's resulting in a lot of redundant `if` statements. Is there a better way to organise this `class` to achieve the same result?

Comment: Do you have any other mutable fields, than `state`?

Comment: @RandallFlagg Yes, I've paired back this example for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Use es6/5 proxies

Comment: @robertotomás As in `get`, `set`, `has` etc?

Comment: Yes, in your case the handler object just needs set

Comment: @robertotomás There's no such thing as ES5 proxies. Proxies are slow and shouldn't be recommended without knowing the context.

Comment: Change detection is one of primary concerns for modern frameworks and can be addressed in several totally different ways. The relationship between methods and `state` in your example is unclear. Why is it toggled on method call in the first place? Does the question presume that it is always toggled? A practical example that explains what you're trying to do would probably help.

Comment: You can derive from an EventEmitter and then put your state variables behind a setter and then anytime its value is changed, the setter can trigger an event which anyone can listen for.  Each section of code would listen for the events it is interested in.  Any changes to the state would automatically trigger the events to fire and all relevant listeners to be called.

Comment: @jfriend00 This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. Something like this? https://netbasal.com/javascript-the-magic-behind-event-emitter-cce3abcbcef9

Comment: @estus sorry I meant 2015, not es5. Proxies impart about a 25x cost for a nulop handler method. That sounds bad, until you realize that 250 or so clock cycles are pretty tiny anywhere where you might not be expected to know what one is. It is a fine general use solution   that's why it was added as part of the standard.

Comment: @robertotomás The decrease in performance vs regular props and descriptors was anywhere from 25 to 1000 in my measurements. The performance differs between engines, and set generally is much slower than get. Since proxies are most helpful in places that are prone to be performance-critical, this generally narrows down their use; nobody wants to write code that is slow by design and has no chance to be optimized further. Hope this will improve in future engine versions.

Comment: @estrus - agreed, performance needs to improve and the best use cases for engineers happens to be in performance critical areas. You're not likely to need that with specific dao/object level implementation level, though. its fine for typical use. Performance _is_ rapidly improving. There was a two fold improvement from chrome 61 to chrome 62. -- engines have only begun to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use an event driven system based on the `EventEmitter()` object built into node.js.

To keep track of state changes, you can define a setter for your state variables so that any time someone sets a new state, then your setter function will get called and it can then trigger an event that indicates the state changed.  Meanwhile, anyone in your object out outside your object can register an event listener for state changes.

Here's a short example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class ClassExample extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(state = 0) {
        super();
        // declare private state variable
        let internalState = state;
        // define setter and getter for private state variable
        Object.defineProperty(this, "state", {
            get: function() {
                return internalState;
            },
            set: function(val) {
                if (internalState !== val) {
                    internalState = val;
                    // send out notification 
                    this.emit("stateChanged", val);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

let e = new ClassExample(1);
console.log(e.state);

e.on("stateChanged", function(newVal) {
    console.log("state has changed to ", newVal);
});

e.state = 3;
console.log(e.state);
```